# Confused about the electric field at the surface of a conductor

Tags: electrostatics

We know that the electric field at the surface of a conductor only have a normal component equal to $\rho/\varepsilon$ (finite number).

But let’s consider the point $\text{P}$ (at the surface of a conductor). Assume that there is a charge at an infinitesimal distance from the point $\text{p}$. We can obtain the field at the $\text{P}$ by the formula $E=Kq/r$. Obviously, $E\sim1/r$. So the normal component of the field is infinite. Now if we add the field due to other charges, it will remain infinite. So where could I be possibly wrong?

Comment: Nowhere! Field is not defined on the surface of conductor, it **is** $\infty$.

Comment: Are you sure? Can't you approximate the electric field at the surface of the conductor to be the midpoint between zero and the magnitude of the jumpy discontinuity? Specifically, as $E_{surface} = \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$.

Answer (score 5):

Implicit in the derivation of $E=\rho/2\epsilon_0$ (you were off by a factor of two by the way) is the assumption that the charge can be approximated by a continuous charge distribution. You correctly note that as you approach a real sheet of charge composed of point charges this treatment breaks down. Let's calculate the $z$-component of the electric field of a square array of equal point charges $q$ located on the $x-y$ plane at lattice sites $(a i, a j, 0)$, where $a$ is the lattice spacing and $i,j$ are integers. Using Coulomb's law you get:

$$ E_{z}=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\sum_{i,j=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{z}{\left(a^{2}i^{2}+a^{2}j^{2}+z^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}. $$

This can't apparently be written in closed form (tried Mathematica). Here is an approximate numerical calculation of this function. $z$ is measured in units of $a$ but the vertical scale is arbitrary (actually $E_z \to 2\pi$ on this scale):

[image]

Note that as $z\to 0$ the field diverges as $z^{-2}$, as you note.

We can get the large distance limit by taking $a\to 0$ and $q\to 0$ such that $q/a^2 = \rho$ is the finite constant charge density. We replace $ a i = x $ and $ a j = y $ and note that, since for large $z$ the summand is a smooth function of $i,j$ the sum can be replaced by an integral:

$$ a^{2}\sum_{i,j=-\infty}^{\infty} \to \int\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y. $$

The result is

$$ E_{z}=\frac{\rho}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\int\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\ \frac{z}{\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}, $$

which straightforwardly evaluates to $E_z = \rho/2\epsilon_0$. By passing into the continuum limit you lose all information about the discreteness at short distances.

Comment: what you mean is that the sum of infinite electrical fields does not add to infinite but it converges to ρ/2ϵ0 ? and this is proven mathematically?

Answer (score 0):

The conductor would be influenced by the point charge: additional charge would build up at the conductor surface until the tangential component of the field has vanished (as usual).

The Wikipedia page about [mirror charges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges) (see picture on the right) illustrates the final configuration. Imagine the infinitesimal distance by moving the charge closer to the surface: the infinitesimal distance would lead to a dipole, where the charge with opposite sign is the 'virtual' mirror charge in the conductor.