# Flux due to charge placed ON a sphere

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

**Question**

If we place a charge, say Q, ON the surface of a sphere, will there be a flux through the sphere?

**My Understanding of the Concept**

I'm studying high school physics, so I have learnt Gauss's Law and according to it *if a charge is placed inside the sphere, a flux is produced*. And *if the charge is placed outside the sphere, the net flux through the sphere is 0 as entering flux equals the leaving flux.*

So while practicing a few workout exercises, I encountered this particular problem:

*A uniformly charged conducting sphere of 2.4 m diameter has a surface charge density of 80 μC/m^2.
So, what is the total electric flux leaving the surface of the sphere?*

So over here I assumed the answer will be zero as the charged enclosed within the surface of the sphere is 0 so flux becomes 0 from the Gauss's formula that says *flux=q(enclosed)/epsilon*
The reason due to which I assumed charge inside is 0 is because the question says surface charge density, which basically is **(Net Charge)/Area**, rather than volume charge density.

Please kindly help me with this

Comment: Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate : [Using Gauss's law when point charges lie exactly on the Gaussian surface](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/544453/) ([A Generalization  of  Gauss's  Theorem  in Electrostatics](http://www.electrostatics.org/images/2011_C3.pdf)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Gauss's law when point charges lie exactly on the Gaussian surface](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/544453/)

Comment: @Frobenius Not a duplicate one...even I saw that ques ...that ques speaks very specifically for a point charge placed on the surface of a cube... where only 1/8th portion of the charge is available inside the closed surface... this it's obvious that Gaussian law can be used there.

Comment: @Frobenius Next time before marking my ques as a duplicate, please carefully analyze what I'm looking for & what the ques u "think" is being duplicated is saying.  No offence but your comment makes me assume that you really dont have much knowledge about this concept...and is simply misusing your previliges to mark ques as duplicate

Comment: @Frobenius I would also be happy if you reopen my ques

Comment: @Frobenius The question being reopened is independent of the accepted answer. The vote to be reopened is for the question. If you do not think the question is a duplicate then you should vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem statement asks for the net flux *leaving* the sphere, not *through* the sphere as you initially stated.

Therefore you would imagine a closed surface outside the sphere, e.g., another imaginary sphere. Then, per Gauss' law the net flux produced by the charged sphere across the surface of the imaginary sphere is

$$\phi=\frac{Q}{e}$$

where $Q$ is the net charge on the sphere and $\epsilon$ is the electrical permittivity of the space.

In this case

$$Q=\pi d^{2}\sigma$$

Where $d$ is the diameter of the charged sphere and $\sigma$ is the charge density on the sphere.

Hope this helps

Comment: The surface area of a sphere is $\frac{1}{4} \pi d^2$?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Mike thanks. It is $4\pi r^2=\pi d^2$

Comment: Bob, in my opinion the net flux *leaving* the sphere is half of yours
\begin{equation}
\phi= \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{Q}{\epsilon}
\tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}

Comment: @Frobenius The charge enclosed by a surface that surrounds (is outside of) the charged sphere is the  surface area of the charged sphere time the surface charge density. Divide that by the permittivity. Where do you get the half from.?

Comment: Think of a point charge $\:q\:$ on the $\:xy-$plane of a system $\:xyz$. The flux upwards ($z+$) is in a solid angle $\:2\pi\:$
so $\:1/2(q/\epsilon)$. Similarly the flux downwards ($z-$) is in a solid angle $\:2\pi\:$ so $\:1/2(q/\epsilon)$. So, any infinitesimal or point charge $\:q\:$ on the spherical surface produces flux $\:1/2(q/\epsilon)\:$ outwards (leaving) and flux $\:1/2(q/\epsilon)\:$ inwards the sphere.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean. They’re asking for the total flux leaving the surface of the sphere. To me that means the flux across a closed surface (not a plane) enclosing the charged sphere. Then the flux is total charge on the sphere divided by the permitivity per Gauss’s law

Comment: Ok, Bob, thanks for your attention. Let leave it as it is. I hope either me or you will realize  in the future where is the right and  where is the wrong.

Comment: No problem. But I don’t think it’s a matter of who’s right or wrong. It just seems we are answering different questions. The total flux would be Q/2e, for example, across any infinite plane outside the sphere because it’s the projection of the surface of the sphere on the plane. But if it’s the total flux leaving the sphere we want to know we apply Gauss’s law which is Q/e. Anyway, take care

Answer (score 1):

If the charge is uniformly distributed on the surface of the sphere, place a spherical Gaussian anywhere outside the surface to get the outward flux (which will appear to be from a point charge).