# Gauss's law in deducing electric field on surface of a sphere conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

We know that the electric field inside and outside of a spherical conductor is given by $0$ and $\frac{kq}{r^2}$ respectively. The 2nd formula is derived using Gauss's law by creating a spherical gaussian surface at the distance we are interested in. But Gauss's law states that the flux is $\frac{q_{\mathrm{inside}}}{\epsilon_0}$. But if we consider the sphere itself as the gaussian surface forthe distance $r=R$,we are assuming that a charge $q$ is inside the surface whereas the charge $q$ is on the surface. So no $q_{\mathrm{inside}}$ exists in this case. How are we then still being able to apply the Gauss law?

Below I have attached a picture of an article claiming that the result is actually $\frac{kq}{2R^2}$. Now I am really confused since untill this day I knew it to be $\frac{kq}{R^2}$ but didn't know the proof. Kindly clear this confusion.

[image]

Comment: [Complete article](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/023/11/1215-1223)

Comment: I have that article,asking for article wasn't my intention

Comment: Related **(1)**  : [Using Gauss's law when point charges lie exactly on the Gaussian surface](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544453/using-gausss-law-when-point-charges-lie-exactly-on-the-gaussian-surface/544481#544481) ([A Generalization  of  Gauss's  Theorem  in Electrostatics](http://www.electrostatics.org/images/2011_C3.pdf)).

Comment: Related **(2)**  : [Trajectory of electric field lines](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/667475/trajectory-of-electric-field-lines/668506#668506).

Comment: I didn’t post the article for you. I posted it for other readers who might want to read more of the calculation than you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Where does "the surface" starts and ends going from the center to the outside? Does a shell of zero thickness really exists?
So, I think you have to consider a "limit" condition with r > R and tends to R (R+).
I also read that article, basically if it works or not :) it's a useful exercise of logic.
In the real life you can deal with potential and electric field very very close to the surface, but not exactly at distance 0 from the shell of 0 thickness. :)
[EDITED] Also, if we consider the "surface" like a shell of some Angstrom thickness, we should assume that for a "point" test charge the Electric field right oh that shell is very variable due to the distance among the test charge position and effectiive charge particle on the shell: in that way we sould consider an "average value" on the entire surface.