# Convergence of Gravitational Potential with continuous mass distribution

Tags: potential

Wikipedia lists the gravitational potential as
$$V(\vec{x})=-\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} 
\frac{\rho(\vec{r})G}{|\vec{x}-\vec{r}|}
dv(\vec{r})
$$
with $dv(\vec{r})$ the volume element, G the gravitational constant and $\rho$ the mass density.
I wonder how and when the integral converges, in particular around $\vec{x}$ and towards infinity? What are required conditions for the mass density and how does this match a posssibly finite universe? In case of negative answers, does general relativity fare better?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/249559/is-the-electric-field-of-a-volume-charge-distribution-well-defined

Comment: In GR energy is a somewhat elusive quantity. In an expanding universe [it isn't even conserved](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/total-energy-of-the-universe).