# Regarding charge densities and the amount of charge located on a point for continuous charge distributions

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge

Suppose we have a volume $V$ containing a charge distribution defined by $\rho (\textbf{x})$.

The amount of charge $q~(P)$ located at an arbitrary point $P(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$ is :

$$q(P)=\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{0}}\int_{y_{0}}^{y_{0}}\int_{z_{0}}^{z_{0}}\rho(\textbf{x}) \,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\mathrm \,dz=0 \,C$$

This means that the charge at each point insde of $\,V$ is equal to zero coulomb, yet $V$ was defined to be a volume containing charges.

Where does this contradiction come from?

Comment: You're integral isn't covering any volume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The charge density of a point charge $q$ at $\mathbf{r}_0$ is a [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function):

$$\rho(\mathbf{r})=q\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0).$$

Its integral over any volume containing $\mathbf{r}_0$ is $q$, not 0.

However, you didn’t integrate over any volume at all.

Comment: Technically the OP didn't say the distribution was a single charge. But they accepted so oh well :)

Comment: But there is still a small contradiction from the answer posted by tparker in this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/249559/is-the-electric-field-of-a-volume-charge-distribution-well-defined). Here's the part of the answer that confuses me "remember that strictly speaking, for a continuous charge distribution with no delta functions in the density, $\rho(\textbf{x})$ is not the amount of charge at point $\textbf{x}$. There is zero charge exactly at point $\textbf{x}$.". 
And so if the charge at each $\textbf{x}$ equals zero, then how does the total charge not equal zero?

Comment: You have to decide if you want to think of charges as discrete point charges or as a continuous, “smeared out,”charge distribution. If the latter, then there is infinitesimal charge $dq=\rho dV$ in infinitesimal volume $dV$.

Comment: @G. Smith, my apologies, I think I rushed a little bit before accepting your answer. Indeed as Aaron Stevens pointed, the volume contains infinitesimal charges distributed over a volume,not point charges.

Comment: As in my previous comment, there are two ways to model charge distributions: discrete or continuous.

Comment: If we use the continuous model, then, in essence, this tells us that there is no charge at a single point, isn'it?

Comment: That’s correct.

Comment: But then if there is no charge located at a point, how could a small element $dv$ have an amount of charge at all?

Comment: That is like asking, if a point has no volume, how can space have volume.

Comment: So this more of a mathematical question than a physics one. Perhaps I could find some insight at Math.SE .

Comment: Mathematicians are better at pondering the mysteries of the continuum: how an infinite number of nothings makes a something. Physicists just think, “Yeah, that seems reasonable to me.” :) (Actually, I think a lot of physicists don’t even believe in a physical continuum. Personally, I think spacetime is probably discrete in some sense.)

Answer (score 1):

The contradiction is that your integral is not covering any volume. The easy answer is that, by definition, the amount of charge $\text dq$ contained in a volume $\text dV$ at location $\mathbf x$ is just
$$\text dq=\rho(\mathbf x)\,\text dV$$

However, if you wanted to relate this to the integral you could just look at a cubic element of length $2\delta$ on each side centered on your point, and then look at what happens as $\delta$ approaches $0$.
$$q=\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}\int_{y_0-\delta}^{y_0+\delta}\int_{z_0-\delta}^{z_0+\delta}\rho(\mathbf x)\,\text dz\,\text dy\,\text dx$$
$$\lim_{\delta\to0}\,q=\text dq=\rho(x_0,y_0,z_0)\,\text dV$$

Something to keep in mind that it seems like is tripping you up: $\text dV$ is not a point. It is still a volume. $\text dV$ technically still has an "infinite number of points" contained within it.